# Having trouble converting a request to python requests

Tags: python, http, web, curl, python-requests

Hi I'm having issue in porting a curl request to python

```
curl --location 'https://XXXX.com/file/upload' --header 'access-token: XXXXXXXX' --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=D8545B9B0589ACD536E224A40537ED39' --form 'file=@"/C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxx.zip"' --form 'UploadData="{\"aaaa\":\"aaaa\",\"version\":\"26.005.10072\"}";type=application/json'
```

Here is my python code:

```
    url = "https://XXXXXX.com/symbol/upload"

    payload = {'UploadData': '{"aaaa":"aaaa","version":"23.005.10072"}'}

    
    files=[('file',('file',open(zipped_file_location,'rb')))]

    header = {
        'access-token': xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header,files=files)
```

I have tried postman code snippet feature but it didn't work. Getting 415 with the Python's code

**reason **is that 'Content-Type: application/json' is not getting added in my HTTP request under form-data; name="UploadData":

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------488196413092784948314604
Cookie: JSESSIONID=5D96B5385CD957521F5E3DA2397ACE83
Content-Length: 6856215
 
----------------------------488196413092784948314604
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="xxxxx.zip"
<Symbols.zip>
----------------------------488196413092784948314604
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadData"
Content-Type: application/json
{"xxxx":"yyyyy","version":"26.005.10072"}
----------------------------488196413092784948314604--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use both `data` and `files` arguments with requests. Instead, you should populate the `files` parameter with both the file and the `UploadData` structures. Then you can set the Content-Type of the `UploadData` as you wish.

See more information [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python).

Comment: You mean  like this files ={
        'file':('abcd.zip',open(zipped_location,'rb')),
        'UploadData':(json.dumps(UploadDataJSON),'application/json')
    }

Comment: Tried  files=[
  ('file',('Files.zip',open(zipped_location,'rb'),'application/zip')),
        ('UploadData',(None,json.dumps(UploadDataJSON),'application/json'))
] getting 404

Comment: HTTP 404 is not found. You have invalid URL.