# How to send TSV file with multipart/form-data to AWS with python request?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, csv, postman, multipartform-data

How to send TSV file with multipart/form-data to AWS with python request?
I used this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python?newreg=6752621a0a884074aa1fffed79191bac)  as a reference,

・When I run it in VScode, it doesn't even reach the AWS gateway (no logs on the gateway either).

・When I run it with Postman, it reaches the AWS gateway, but comes back with a "message": "Unsupported Media Type" error.And also no logs on the lambda.

What are some of the problems I am having?

==Python ===

```
def main():
    file_path = 'files/data.tsv'
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'file': (file_name, open(file_path, 'rb'), 'text/tab-separated-values')
        }
    )

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type,
        'Singnature': SECRET_KEY
    }

    try:
        r = requests.post(ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data=multipart_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

==postman===

URL,header are same as python

body,form-data,key:file,value:data.tsv

==AWS===

Binary media types:multipart/form-data

==template===

```
{
  "headers": {
#foreach( $name in $input.params().header.keySet() )
    "$name" : "$util.escapeJavaScript( $input.params().header.get( $name ) )"
  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
  },
  "body": "$util.escapeJavaScript( $input.body ).replaceAll("\\'","'")"
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to set Content-Type.  That might be part of the problem because it should be something like multipart/form-data .  I was just working on code that does this and it was surprisingly hard to get right.  I used https://httpbin.org/post quite a bit to debug what Python was sending and how it differed from `curl`.

Comment: In other words, something like "requests.post(ENDPOINT, data=multipart_data)"?
But can I handle data.tsv data in lambda?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  I didn't use MultipartEncoder either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html):

> With non-proxy integrations, when a method request carries a payload and either the `Content-Type` header does not match any specified mapping template or no mapping template is defined, you can choose to pass the client-supplied request payload through the integration request to the backend without transformation. The process is known as integration passthrough.
>
> For proxy integrations, API Gateway passes the entire request through to your backend, and you do not have the option to modify the passthrough behaviors.

When you're sending `multipart/form-data` as a content type and getting a "415: Unsupported media type", it means that:

1. Your integration is not a proxy ("Lambda proxy integration" is off in the console)
2. The integration passthrough behaviour ("Request body passthrough") is set to "Never"
3. There is no mapping template for `multipart/form-data`

You need to fix this one way or another:

1. Make your integration a proxy integration. This way, your Lambda gets a [structured event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) with all the details of the HTTP request in it, and it should return a [structured response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format). You'll need to rewrite your Lambda to handle the processing and generation of all these structures.
2. Enable request body passthrough for non-JSON payloads. The downside is that your lambda will receive all content types, not just `multipart/form-data`, and  the actual content type will not get passed to it.
3. Create an identity VTL template for `multipart/form-data` with this content:

   ```
   $input.body
   ```

   and leave "Request body passthrough" set to "Never". This way, only `multipart/form-data` requests will reach your lambda.

Note that unless you're sending your data from an HTML form on a browser page, you probably don't need `multipart/form-data`. You'll need to import additional libraries to handle it on the Lambda side, with no extra benefits.

Since you are using Python to generate your data anyway, you would be better off converting it to JSON (*editor's choice*), or sending it as a plain text (`text/plain` or `text/tab-separated-data`).

All runtimes that support Lambda have built-in JSON support. In addition, you can create a [validator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html) and check your JSON data for valitity in the API Gateway, at no extra charge.

Comment: Sorry for late response and Thank you for giving the answer.
I have a question I added the template because headers {} have "content type" and "secreat keys". But even I added template, It doesn't work.

```
{
  "headers": {
#foreach( $name in $input.params().header.keySet() )
    "$name" : "$util.escapeJavaScript( $input.params().header.get( $name ) )"
  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
  },
  "body": "$util.escapeJavaScript( $input.body ).replaceAll("\\'","'")"
}
```

Comment: @上嶋光優: please update your question with all this information. Make sure to specify what kind of integration you're using, where you added the template, and what exactly it means that "it doesn't work". Thank you.

Comment: @ Quassnoi: sorry for making confuse.I updated that.

Comment: @上嶋光優: what exactly does it mean that "it doesn't work"? Please don't answer here, update the post

Comment: Ah... never mind. I mean just I have "Unsupported Media Type" error  even I have a template