# Required attribute Not working with File input in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a file upload control in my form.I am using Angular JS .
When I put the required attribute to validate that the file is selected it is not working.

```
<input id="userUpload" name="userUpload" required type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Ok</button>
```

Can you please suggest why the required is not working ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) that does the validation in Angular based on attributes like `require`. However, currently there is no support for `input type="file"` with the ng-model service. To get it working you could create a directive like this:

```js
app.directive('validFile',function(){
  return {
    require:'ngModel',
    link:function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel){
      //change event is fired when file is selected
      el.bind('change',function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
          ngModel.$render();
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Example markup:

```html
  <div ng-form="myForm">
    <input id="userUpload" ng-model="filename" valid-file name="userUpload" required type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Ok</button>
    <p>
      Input is valid: {{myForm.userUpload.$valid}}
      <br>Selected file: {{filename}}
    </p>
  </div>
```

Check out [my working plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3TZCMUb9XXPGP5ifHf6x?p=preview).

Comment: I have already included SHIV for IE. I am going to put this code.will this work ?

Comment: I don't even know what your code does - my sniplet should be IE8 compatible. Include it, test it and if it doesn't work in IE8 create a new question

Comment: You can test http://run.plnkr.co/CEMX0RY3MX1TbcSZ/ in IE8 (I just did and it worked fine)

Comment: Your example throws an exception in jQuery.

Comment: @JonRimmer It's a little bug in the directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383446/how-to-validate-form-with-inputtype-file-in-angularjs

Comment: This wasn't resetting for me when I re-opened the form in a modal, so I had to add `ngModel.$setViewValue("");` as the first line of the `link` function and now it works sweet. Thanks! Though it would be nice for this to auto-majicially hook into `:input[type='file'][required]`! I could do this easily in jQuery, but Angular... research here I come!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. I would suggest to name it 'passFile' since it actually passes the file path to the model (that then can validate it)

Answer (score 11):

Extending @joakimbl code I will suggest the direct like this

```
.directive('validFile',function(){
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function(scope,el,attrs,ctrl){
            ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', el.val() != '');
            //change event is fired when file is selected
            el.bind('change',function(){
                ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', el.val() != '');
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(el.val());
                    ctrl.$render();
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

and in html you can use like this

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" ng-model="myFile" valid-file />
<label ng-show="myForm.myFile.$error.validFile">File is required</label>
```

Comment: It's kind of odd, but using your code properly sets `myForm.myFile.$error.validFile` to true, but ng-show is not working. Using `myForm.myFile.$invalid` is working properly. I don't get why is it. My angular inspector shows validFile as true...

Comment: Okay, I got it... i changed validFile to valid-file, and i was looking for `myForm.myFile.$error.valid` minus `file`