# How to access file in renderer function?

Tags: angularjs

I saw a solution to:
[How to validate form with input[type=file] in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383446/how-to-validate-form-with-inputtype-file-in-angularjs/18383800#18383800)

I was wondering if it is possible to check e.g. the mimetype or the file size inside the renderer?
I dont only want to set the current selected file (for required input field file) i also like to check if the file is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. With file api. In file change callback, you can handle the file with this code:

```
myApp.directive('validFile', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            var maxSize = 100;
            var invalidSize = true;
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                // when you setValidity 'invalidSize' to false
                // then you 'form.myfile.$error.invalidSize' will be true.
                ngModel.$setValidity('invalidSize', invalidSize);
            };
            el.bind('change', function(evt){
                console.log(evt);
                var files = evt.target.files; // You can handle multifile here but need input file set multiple attribute
                var file = files[0];
                console.log(file); // You can see all these attribute here.
                console.log(file.size);
                if(file.size > maxSize){
                    invalidSize = false;
                }else{
                    invalidSize = true;
                }
                scope.$apply(ngModel.$render);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Here is file api document.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File)

#### [Here is DEMO Code.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/1p358gwk/2/)

Comment: i would like this to be done in the directive from this solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383446/how-to-validate-form-with-inputtype-file-in-angularjs/18383800#18383800) How to validate form with input[type=file] in angularjs

Comment: @user1429166 Just change my answer. Create my own jsfiddle with file directive validation. Can you check my answer again?

Comment: first: elm.bind should be el.bind
but its not working - i have a button to sumbmit the form with the property ng-disabled="!uploadform.$valid" but it does not render valid anymore now. doesnt matter if i select a small or big file

Comment: @user1429166 Don't understand what you are talking about. Can you  post your code into jsfiddle with some comment?

Comment: in function you have 'el' but for bind you use 'elm' anyway - i could get it working. thanks to you! very cool. thanks for your time and effort