# How to get file content and other details in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms, angularjs-fileupload

How can I get file content while I click on submit button. I'm getting only first and second input.
Please refer to snippet:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <input type="file" ng-model="user.file">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
  <p>master = {{master}}</p>
</div>
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.reset = function(){
   console.log($scope.user)
   }
   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to read the file contents?

Comment: yes on console, I want to get file info like i m getting firstname and lastnme. @GangadharJannu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a directive to handle file in forms (as suggested by joakimbl in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207202/required-attribute-not-working-with-file-input-in-angular-js/16208884#16208884)):

```
app.directive('validFile',[function() {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    scope : {format: '@', upload : '&upload'},
    link : function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      // change event is fired when file is selected
      el.bind('change', function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        scope.upload({file:event.target.files[0]});
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
          ngModel.$render();
        });
      })
    }
  }
}]);
```

in your HTML

```
<input type="file" valid-file upload="uploadFile(file)" ng-model="file">
```

Here `uploadFile` will be a function in your controller where you can get contetnts of file

Controller code

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(element) {
    $scope.user.file = element;
    console.log($scope.user);
  }
```

please have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n6bxylUzgY7fMq9EStLy?p=preview)

Comment: Any other way without directive. @nishantagrawal

Comment: I think he dont want to upload the file. He just want to get the file content.

Comment: I just want to send the file details to backend, so just for testing purpose, I console the data that is going in backend, I found that -> {
  "firstName": "dd",
  "lastName": "dd"
} but file content missing. One way of doing is using Directives. I want to know is this possible without Directive? @lin

Comment: @Mohammed my solution doesnt work with directives. So the answer is yes. What are you missing?

Comment: Thanks for that but cant this possible in pure AngularJS instead of using JS part?@lin

Comment: @Mohammed Not possible, thats why I did not deliver you a answer which  uses  AngularJS core directives.

Comment: How can I use the valid-file-upload only after click of submit button, currently what happening is while I upload the file it sends the data, I want that think on click of submit button alongwith form data this file data should go. @lin

Comment: @Mohammed i dont know. This is not my answer but you marked it as the right one. My answer is the other one.

Answer (score 6):

You can't access the file content directly by using `ng-scopes` but you are able to read the file content with native JavaScript [FileAPI](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/). Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz9gnemn/4/). I think you want to display the file content without uploading them on server side. It's not 100% clear what you want so thats how you can get the **filecontent**, **filesize** and **filename** in browser without uploading.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" id="myFileInput" />
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="submit()">
    Submit
  </button>
  <br /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <h1>
    Filename: {{ fileName }}
  </h1>
  <h2>
    File size: {{ fileSize }} Bytes
  </h2>
  <h2>
    File Content: {{ fileContent }}
  </h2>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS App

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fileContent = '';
    $scope.fileSize = 0;
    $scope.fileName = '';
    $scope.submit = function () {
      var file = document.getElementById("myFileInput").files[0];
      if (file) {
        var aReader = new FileReader();
        aReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
        aReader.onload = function (evt) {
            $scope.fileContent = aReader.result;
            $scope.fileName = document.getElementById("myFileInput").files[0].name;
            $scope.fileSize = document.getElementById("myFileInput").files[0].size;;
        }
        aReader.onerror = function (evt) {
            $scope.fileContent = "error";
        }
      }
    }
});
```