# A Simple Uploader using AngularJs (with CORS Implementation)

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, blueimp, uploader

Recently, I had to write a simple uploader (reusable) using AngularJs, while, keeping my API in separate place and finally wrote one using [blueimp jQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and made lil  customizing it. I Thought it might be great to share this and hopefully improve myself in learning in AngularJs. (I've added the answer)

Comment: This is great, Is there a 'how do I' question that could be asked here, so that people discover it easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codelikeapoem.com/2013/05/angularjs-tutorial-4-file-upload-using.html
(You can download the entire code their)

App.Coffee

```
@angTut = angular.module("angTut", ['LocalStorageModule', 'ngResource', 'uploaderComponent']);

@angTut.constant('uploadServiceUrl', 'http://192.168.0.2/api/index.php')
```

todos_uploader_controller.coffee

```
"use strict"
@angTut.controller('TodosUploadController', (
$scope, uploadService
) ->

$scope.uploadLayer = (e, data, process) ->
    $scope.uploadReturn = uploadService.process(e, data, process)
    $scope.uploadReturn = uploadService.initialize() 
)
```

uploader.directive

https://gist.github.com/sk8terboi87/5652187

upload.html

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <input id="testUpload" type="file" fileupload name="files[]" uploadurl="uploadReturn.uploadurl" done="uploadLayer(e, data, 'done')" fail="uploadLayer(e, data, 'fail')" progress="uploadLayer(e, data, 'progress')">
       <div class="well" ng-show="uploadReturn.status">
       {{uploadReturn.message}}
        <div ng-show="!uploadReturn.error">
            <p class="label label-info">File: {{uploadReturn.successData.name}}</p>
            <p><a href="{{uploadReturn.successData.fullUrl}}" target="_blank">View file</a></p>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```