# How do i get the content from a formData?

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have created a file into the formData like this:

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
```

how do i get the content out of the formData? like the filename and the file?
something like this?: `fd.filename()`, `fd.getData()`.
or `fd.get('file')` to retrieve the file back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the files after you've appended them in to a formData-object I believe.

You'll have to send the formData-object somewhere and then get the files from a req-object or something like that.

In my case (angularJS + nodeJS) I tested this from an answer on SO (link below):

Angular:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
$http({
  method:"POST",
  url:"uploadFile",
  data: fd,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
  transformRequest: angular.identity
});
```

Node (expressJS):

```
app.post('/uploadFile', function(req,res){
  fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function(err, data){
    // Do something with the data (which holds the file information)
  });
});
```

To see what you can do with the file, read this:
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

The code is taken from :
[AngularJS: how to implement a simple file upload with multipart form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963022/angularjs-how-to-implement-a-simple-file-upload-with-multipart-form)

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone that gives the desired answer

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
 var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('file', file);
```

Then use this:

```
   var newfile = fd.get('file');
      console.log(newfile.name);       //filename
      console.log(newfile.size);       //filesize
```

Or this for arrays:

```
 for (var newfile of fd.getAll('file')){
     console.log(newfile.name);
     console.log(newfile.size);
}
```

Then you can append file to another FormData:

```
var newFormData = new FormData();
    newFormData.append('file', newfile);
```

If you want get all data from FormData, not only file, use FormData.entries() :

```
for (var pair of fd.entries())
    {
     console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);   //property and value pairs
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the filedata like that. If you want to send the file to a servlet. try this

Get your file

```
var files=document.getElementById('fileID').files[0];
```

Now append your file to formdata and send it by ajax ;

```
fd.append('file',files);
```

Note: form enctype should be multipart/formdata

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the content like that. The only method availble is append

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Then how do i solve it then? if i want to save the file?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [these](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/formdata-interface-coming-to-firefox/) [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) [articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it looks like there is no way to get data out of a FormData object.  You can only use them for building FormData to send via an AJAX request.

One way around this would be to build up a regular dictionary and then convert it to FormData:

```
var myFormData = {
    key1: 300,
    key2: 'hello world'
};

var fd = new FormData();
for (var key in myFormData) {
    console.log(key, myFormData[key]);
    fd.append(key, myFormData[key]);
}
```

If you want to debug a plain FormData object, you could also send it in order to examine it in the network request console of your developer tools:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

> Here's some proof of concept code to **[Drag and Drop files into FormData](http://jsbin.com/puteru/11/edit?html,output)** and upload via POST to a server. I also made a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/lofogo/edit?js,output) where you can experiment and see what data is inside of a FormData object if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get the list of the data that content from the `FormData` API using the getter function.

Example:

```
formData.getAll('medias') // returns a list of all the files tied to the key 'medias'

Result: [File, File, File, File, File]
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

There are other methods available with the API!