# Why POST using a 'Form' vs using a 'Body'?

Tags: asp.net, angular

The title expresses my post succinctly.  Though the following side-note expresses my specific situation which sparked the question.

> *Side Note:  I'm making a web app with an Angular Front-end.  I've found that once I encapsulate my data in a 'FormData' object from an
>   html form template, I am then unable to get those values back from
>   within client-side Angular (as posts like this one state:
>   [How do i get the content from a formData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404476/how-do-i-get-the-content-from-a-formdata)
>   ).  Though when I POST to ASP.Net with a '[FromForm]' attribute the
>   values get mapped fine.
>
> So to make things easier I might rather acquire data from the form in
>   the first place and then use it in a 'body' POST instead of a 'form'
>   POST.  Doing this so that I am passing around straight data I can work
>   with, instead of data wrapped in a form which I'm unable to work with
>   client-side.
>
> So, thus, I'm wondering the differences between Posting 'forms' and
>   posting 'bodies', and whether there's any reason I should use one over
>   the other?
>
> **Update**
>
> In ASP.Net Core you can put attributes on your parameter types for REST endpoints.  [FromForm] and [FromBody] are what I'm curious about.  On the angular side, calling these REST endpoints requires passing either a 'FormData' (for the [FromForm]), or some sort of user defined type (for [FromBody]).
>
> See below for examples.

**Update**

Here's the signature for the ASP.NET Endpoint for the '[FromBody]':

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] LoginViewModel model) 
{...}
```

Here's the Angular snippet that calls this '[FromBody]' endpoint, along with the type that is passed in for the POST call:

```
public creds = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
}

login(creds): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.post("api/account/createtoken", creds)
  .pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      this.token = data.token;
      this.tokenExpiration = data.expiration;
      this.username = data.username;
      return true;
    }));
}
```

Here is the signature for the ASP.NET Endpoint for the '[FromForm]':

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Signup([FromForm] SignupViewModel viewModel)
{...}
```

and here is the Angular snippet that calls this '[FromForm]' endpoint:

```
registerUser(formData: FormData) {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json')
    };
    return this.http.post('api/account/signup', formData, options)
      .pipe(
      map(() => {
          return true;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
}
```

Comment: Form data is in a body of a web request (as its not in the headers or the URL), so I don’t understand your question. Can you add some code that demonstrates your problem? Also, do you know what a Content Type is? If not, you should research it, as it may answer your question.

Comment: @Nate, I hope this provides you with more detail on the situation.  Let me know if you require anything more.  I'll look into 'Content Type' as you mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/what-are-the-differences-between-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-url)

Answer (score 1):

The FromForm attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type application/x-www-url-formencoded while the FromBody will parse the model the default way, which in most cases are sent by the content type application/json, from the request body

Comment: Why use one over the other though?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question