# Getting path of a file instead of the file to upload using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code:

```
class DashboardPage extends Component {
  
  handleNewProduct = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(event.target.files);

    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('title', event.target.title.value);
    formData.append('desc', event.target.desc.value);
    formData.append('image', event.target.product.value);

    // console.log(formData);
    formData.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>Enter New product.</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleNewProduct} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Desciption</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="desc"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="product" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

It gets all the information from form and logs in it out. I append the data to `formData` which is an instance of `FormData`. But for file I gets the path of the file. How to get the file to store to formData and then upload it to server using lets say fetch api?

Comment: You cannot do so since browsers don's allow it. But for path when reading, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) might help you

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari I am not planning to preview it. I just want to select a image and enter some information like title and description and then post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/22404816/9554128

You might want to do `event.target.product.files[0]`