# File upload in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to do an AJAX file upload through angularjs.  It is telling me that my form data is improperly formatted, or something like that.

This is my html:

```
<TR>
    <TD class="labelWide" nowrap="nowrap">Upload PDF</TD>
    <TD class="required">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class="data">
        <input type="file" npr-uploader="temporary_upload">
        <button ng-click="uploadFile('pdf')">Load File</button><BR>
        <span ng-repeat="fileItem in data.pdfFiles">{{fileItem.filename}}<BR></span>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

This is my directive:

```
nprDirectives.directive('nprUploader', ['$parse', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.nprUploader);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is the called `uploadFile` function:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(arg_type){
    $scope.data.uploadFile($scope.temporary_upload, arg_type);
};
```

And this is the function in my data service for uploading.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(arg_file,arg_type,arg_key){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("attachment", arg_file);

    var urlType = "other";
    if(arg_type == "pdf"){
        urlType = "pdf";
    }

    $http.post( contextPath+'/uploadFile/ajax/upload/'+urlType, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
.success(stuff happens)
.error(stuff happens);
```

And finally, this is my error message:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Please check your Data
type:  Status Report
message:  Please check your Data
description:  The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Please check your Data.).
```

I also went ahead and looked at the ajax post in the console and see this:

```
-----------------------------168221372516176 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="busicard.pdf" 
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4 
(etc lots of gobblygook because PDF with image)
```

Comment: there is an angular plugin which provides that functionality. you could look at the source code and you may find what you seek: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/master/dist/angular-file-upload.js

Comment: Adding the @Alp comment, you can search a lot of modules to complement you AngularJS code (including 'Upload' modules), at http://ngmodules.org/

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24443918/1162133

Comment: I could be wrong, but last I remember content-type header is used by the server to verify the content. Probably going to need to set that to something that's related to a pdf document like text/pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is being closed because I discovered I WAS formatting the AJAX call in the correct way.  The problem was actually in the java that was receiving the file.  Without making changes to the JavaScript, I managed to get a file to upload.