# Uploading file with form input

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

i've been going from page to page all over the internet trying to find a simple and recommended way of uploading a single file in angularjs, so far i have found none, what i want is to be able to do something like this:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="file" id="form.file" />
<input type="text" ng-model="name" id="form.name" />
```

Then in my controller/service i have a function that posts all my form data:

```
SomeRandomService.save = function($scope.form) {

    return $http
        .post('/api/v1/some/random/url/', $scope.form)

};
```

Is this so difficult in angular? I am a newbie to angular so i can't even understand some of the solutions i have found online.

Is there something way more simpler? A plugin or service or directive that can do this for me?

Comment: Check the search function first :)

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: Have already seen that, the issue i have with those is that they either do not show how to post a file along with text input or they have cross browser compatibility problems or they use some complex alien like code that i can't even understand.  I did find one which seemed to be what i was looking for but they referenced a plugin without adding a link so i dunno how to get it and implement their solution.

Comment: The post i am referring to is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443246/angularjs-how-to-upload-multipart-form-data-and-a-file