# Converting curl POST to comply with the `angular-file-upload` format OR to achieve the same result using a custom Angular $http.post()

Tags: curl, file-upload, angular-http, angular-file-upload

I am having a hard time to convert the following `curl` POST to comply with the `angular-file-upload` format

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --form "jobSettings=$body" --form "upload=@$file" ${URL}?key=$key
```

where:

`@file` - *an image file provided as a parameter to the script call*

`$body` - *a JSON object that describes job parameters required by the server*

Namely, I do not know how to pass `--form` parameters into `formData` of `angular-file-upload` (and even if `formData` is the right property to use for this task).

PS: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504429/1202371) solution for  posting an image as a JSON `multipart/form-data` data without relying on `angular-file-upload`, but I am still not sure how could I format `jobSettings` parameter within the `data` property of the `$http.post()`. I tried the following ways, since according to [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) I am allowed to set data to `String` or Object types:

```
data: 'jobSettings={"analysis": {"paintings": [...]}}'

data: {'jobSettings': {"analysis": {"paintings": [...]}}'
```

Not working.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to achieve the result by using `angular-file-upload` combined with the following setting for `formData` parameter of the `FileUploader()` instances:

```
$scope.uploader.formData.push({'jobSettings': JSON.stringify(jobSettings)});
```