# Http request is different between client and server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http

In client side I send a request with $http:

```
Upload.upload({
       url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
       fields: {
            'username': $scope.username
       },
       file: file
})
```

In server side, this is the route:

```
app.route('/upload')
    .get(function (req) {
        for (var key in req)
            console.log(key);
})
```

But I cannot see any key name file in req? What is the reason for this difference between them two?

Comment: What middleware is the `app` currently using? Any body parsers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers to upload files using post , need to make  multipart/form-data request ,

```
   var fd = new FormData();
     fd.append("file", file);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
```

See [more on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963022/angularjs-how-to-implement-a-simple-file-upload-with-multipart-form)