# Adding files to $scope in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the following input element:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Attach BOL Document</label>
           <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" />
     </div>
```

In my controller (outside of any function) I set a variable like this:

```
 $scope.fd = new FormData();
```

and I have the following function defined that fires onchange of the input element as seen above:

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
    console.log(files[0]);
    $scope.fd.append("file", files[0]);
    console.log($scope.fd);

};
```

The first console.log outputs the File object as I expect so I know that is being passed into my $scope.  The problem is the second console.log outputs an empty FormData object.  The File object is not getting appended??

I thought maybe this was something to do with the fact that I am declaring $scope.fd outside of the UploadFIle function, but even declaring it inside the function does not work...

Why???

Comment: Is it not getting appended or not reflected in the view? because you are not doing `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: what's with the funky reference in `onchange`? there isn't any reason to use `angular.element` in this example, that I'm aware of?

Comment: I think its not getting appended as I see the empty FormData object in the console.log statement showing in the JavaScript console.  I am not trying to update the view with this value, it will be submitted to the server via $http.  The "funky" reference with onchange is due to the fact that ng-model is not supported oin input type "file".  See this post for reference:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963022/angularjs-how-to-implement-a-simple-file-upload-with-multipart-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out whats going on here.  Its got nothing to do with AngularJs.  You cannot inspect the keys added to a FormData object.  See this question for a reference

[How to inspect FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata)

This really stinks...  So until I get the server side code ready and I actually POST the data I cant tell if the file is actually getting appended.  I feel certain it is however I cant validate this.