# How to add multiple files into a array and access files one by one in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add multiple files into a file array and later on access the each files in AngularJs.So far i have created a custom directive to read files looking at some posts.it was working fine with a single file.But my requirement is that i want to upload multiple files and add them into array and later on access the  created file array when accessing the data.I am newbie to AngularJs please help me to achieve this.

**HTML code snippet**

```
    <div class="input input-file  ">
         <span class="button"><input on-read-file="readFileContent($fileContent)" 
    type="file" id="attachments" name="file" data-ng-model="attachments" 
    onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value">Browse</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Attach some files" readonly="">
 </div>
```

**Custom directive for read input files**

```
var mimeType,fileName;
testModule.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {

                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });

                };


                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);

                //Get the Uploaded file mime type 
                mimeType=(onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0].type;
                fileName=(onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0].name;

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Read File Content Method**

```
 $scope.readFileContent = function($fileContent){

   $scope.content = $fileContent;
          };
```

Comment: can you please add fiddle of the code?

Comment: @Kunal Kakkad here is the original fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/ this support only single file upload but i want to upload multiple files and read them later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to check this post on StackOverflow:

[Upload multiple files in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404502/upload-multiple-files-in-angular)

One of the answers contains this working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/B13t84j5IPzINMh1F862?p=preview

It uses a directive named ng-file-model:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple />
```

Comment: Thanks that was the thing i have searched for.

Comment: how can i read file content?Is it possible to send list of file obj into server side and access those file objs?

Comment: use this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211145/upload-file-with-ajax-xmlhttprequest and rewrite upload function