# How to POST data using AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, web-services, networking, post, afnetworking-2

I need to send my data by POST, in variable data.

I do it like this:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email, @"password" : pass };
[manager POST:URLString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }];
```

and have:

```
JSON: {
Data = "<null>";
Message = "unexpected end of JSON input";
Result = fail;
}
```

I know the method

```
  - (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
   constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData>))block
                     success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, id))success
                     failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *, NSError *))failure;
```

But how can I send my dictionary in variable data to the web server?

Comment: hi i need your help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does your web service expect the parameters to be formatted as JSON? If so, before you invoke the `POST` method, you need to tell the `manager` to use a JSON `requestSerializer`, i.e. `AFJSONRequestSerializer`:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

By default, AFNetworking assumes you want to use `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` (i.e. a request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Comment: yep,    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *Data = @{@"email" : email, @"password" : pass };
    NSLog(@"%@",email);
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:Data success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }];

Comment: maybe i need to convert dictionary to json?

Comment: I understand, I need send it in variable data, how can I do this?

Comment: @user3196922 I'm going to prune some of our unrelated discussion out of this question's comments section, and we can [move this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45335/discussion-between-rob-and-user3196922).