# AFNetworking 2.0 POST request not working swift

Tags: post, swift, afnetworking-2

I am facing an issue with AFNetworking 2.0 (coding on Swift). GET method, of library seems that works perfect for me. Although, POST method returns me error. The error is Bad username/password. From the first looking that seem an authentication issue, but actually when I tried the POST request on Postman (REST Client) worked perfect.

So what I am doing:

Configuration:

```
var policy : AFSecurityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy();
policy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;

self.client = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: self.basicUrl)
self.client!.operationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
self.client!.securityPolicy = policy

var responseSerializer : AFJSONResponseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

self.client!.responseSerializer = responseSerializer

var requestSerializer : AFJSONRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

self.client!.requestSerializer = requestSerializer
```

and my request

```
internal func loginUser(email : String, password : String, onCompletion : WebClientLoginResponse) -> Void
{
    var params : Dictionary = ["email":email, "pass":password]

    self.client!.POST("login", parameters: params, success: { (operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response : AnyObject!) -> Void in

        var finalResponse : Dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()

        finalResponse = response as Dictionary

        onCompletion(true, nil, nil, nil)

        }) { (operation : AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

            println("Error \(error.description) \(operation.responseObject) ")

            onCompletion(false, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

What do you think guys? Am I missing anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Does your server require JSON-encoded parameters? See the accepted [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152847/how-to-post-data-using-afnetworking-2-0).

Also, consider using the Swift version of AFNetworking, [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), which has an easier (IMHO) way to set the encoding format.

Comment: Hey Todd thanks for your answer first of all. It seems that the problem was that I was setting requestSerializer as well. (not only responseSerializer). It seems that if you are assigning both of them, POST does not working (for some strange reason). As a result, when I removed the lines, where I was configuring requestSerializer, POST was working properly! I don't know why!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that! Seems like maybe a bug in AFNetworking. Glad it's working now.

Comment: @Tzegenos Thanks, Removing these lines solved the issue for me to!