# Calling web services with the help of AFNetworking in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using NSURLConnection method to call the web services what I want is to replace it with 3rd party library AFNetworking how shall I achieve this I am calling the web Services with data first time here is what I am doing currently.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL * linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@URLBase];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:linkUrl];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/plain; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    }
    else
    {
         NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
   }
#pragma mark -- Connection Delegate
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",response);
    //[webData setLength: 0];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     NSLog(@"\nERROR with theConenction");

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Converted NSData %@ ",responseDataString);

}
```

here

```
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

str is my encrypted data like username and password.
thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send POST request to your web services. You can use below code snippet for old way.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&value=%@&value=%@&value=%@&value=%@&value=%@",self.Comment_Memberid,self.SharedID,self.Post_Ownerid,self.commentText.text,email_stored,password_stored];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.../api/json/postcomment/"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"text/plain; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    //get response
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %ld", (long)[urlResponse statusCode]);

    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200)
    {

    }
```

And if you want to send POST request using with AFNetworking you can use below code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"34": x,
                         @"130": y};
[manager POST:@"https://../api/json/cordinates" parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: My data is in simple TextPlain

Comment: does not matter. You should pass your data to web service with above code. Your data can be image(NSData) or simply a pure string. You can use this code section.