# Uploading image and data as multi part content - windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, upload, multipartform-data

I am unable to upload image and data to web service as multipart content.Here is my code

```
 var fileUploadUrl = @"http://myurl";
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                    photoStream.Position = 0;

                    // This is the postdata
                    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "attendeedImage");
                    content.Add(new StringContent("12", Encoding.UTF8), "userId");
                    content.Add(new StringContent("78", Encoding.UTF8), "noOfAttendees");
                    content.Add(new StringContent("chennai", Encoding.UTF8), "locationName");
                    content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "longitude");
                    content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "latitude");

                    Console.Write(content);
                    // upload the file sending the form info and ensure a result.
                    // it will throw an exception if the service doesn't return a valid successful status code
                    await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
                        .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                        {
                            postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        });
```

The response I get is 400- Bad request

Is is possible to send both image and data together like this?
If yes, what is the proper way to go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but the problem could be a missing boundary between your data items. To specify one, initializting your `MultipartFormDataContent` as follows:

```
string boundary = "---###---"; // should never occur in your data
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
```

More about boundaries: [What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)