# Missing start boundary with jersey 2.15 with WebKit browser (Chrome, Safari)

Tags: java, webkit, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a java application with netty et jersey 2.15.
I tried to upload a file with a multi part form.

```
<form id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://localhost/api/upload">>
        Profile Image: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It's work with Firefox and IE but it's not work with Chrome or Safari

NB. Chrome and Safari use Webkit.

See the data on Firefox (Same on IE)

```
//startContent
-----------------------------2382551017519
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

bar
-----------------------------2382551017519--

//endContent

//byte
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 50, 51, 56, 50, 53, 53, 49, 48, 49, 55, 53, 49, 57, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 68, 105, 115, 112, 111, 115, 105, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 111, 114, 109, 45, 100, 97, 116, 97, 59, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 61, 34, 102, 105, 108, 101, 34, 59, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 110, 97, 109, 101, 61, 34, 102, 111, 111, 46, 116, 120, 116, 34, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 112, 108, 97, 105, 110, 13, 10, 13, 10, 98, 97, 114, 13, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 50, 51, 56, 50, 53, 53, 49, 48, 49, 55, 53, 49, 57, 45, 45, 13, 10

//header
Host : localhost
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept : */*
Accept-Language : fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
Referer : http://10.0.16.56:8080/
Origin : http://10.0.16.56:8080
Connection : keep-alive
Pragma : no-cache
Cache-Control : no-cache
Content-Length : 188
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------2382551017519
```

See data on Chrome (Same on Safari)

```
//[startContent]
------WebKitFormBoundaryg7okV37G7Gfll2hf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

bar
------WebKitFormBoundaryg7okV37G7Gfll2hf--

//[endContent]

//byte
45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 87, 101, 98, 75, 105, 116, 70, 111, 114, 109, 66, 111, 117, 110, 100, 97, 114, 121, 103, 55, 111, 107, 86, 51, 55, 71, 55, 71, 102, 108, 108, 50, 104, 102, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 68, 105, 115, 112, 111, 115, 105, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 102, 111, 114, 109, 45, 100, 97, 116, 97, 59, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 61, 34, 102, 105, 108, 101, 34, 59, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 110, 97, 109, 101, 61, 34, 102, 111, 111, 46, 116, 120, 116, 34, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 112, 108, 97, 105, 110, 13, 10, 13, 10, 98, 97, 114, 13, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 87, 101, 98, 75, 105, 116, 70, 111, 114, 109, 66, 111, 117, 110, 100, 97, 114, 121, 103, 55, 111, 107, 86, 51, 55, 71, 55, 71, 102, 108, 108, 50, 104, 102, 45, 45, 13, 10

//header
Host : localhost
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Accept : */*
Accept-Language : fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
Referer : http://10.0.16.56:8080/
Origin : http://10.0.16.56:8080
Connection : keep-alive


Content-Length : 184
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=----webkitformboundaryg7okv37g7gfll2hf

//ERROR
36691 10:04:19.945 [event-group-5-8] INFO  .c.p.h.HttpJerseyServerHandler - Invoking '/api/nonJaxbResource/upload'
36695 10:04:19.949 [child-group-3-8] WARN  http-server - 58b3f632-6fa3-4a7b-98e7-4ef13e511550 | Missing start boundary
36695 10:04:19.949 [child-group-3-8] ERROR ROOT       - No codec available to display error for 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----webkitformboundaryg7okv37g7gfll2hf'
59215 13:27:52.642 [event-group-5-3] ERROR ROOT       - HTTP 400 Bad Request
 javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:258)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:783)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.getEntity(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:376)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.access$000(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.JerseyApplicationHandlerRuntime$1.run(JerseyApplicationHandlerRuntime.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.JerseyApplicationHandlerRuntime.process(JerseyApplicationHandlerRuntime.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.JerseyApplicationHandler.handle(JerseyApplicationHandler.java:1019)
    ...
Caused by: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.skipPreamble(MIMEParser.java:313)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser.access$300(MIMEParser.java:68)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:149)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParser$MIMEEventIterator.next(MIMEParser.java:132)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.makeProgress(MIMEMessage.java:198)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.parseAll(MIMEMessage.java:181)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEMessage.getAttachments(MIMEMessage.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:179)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403904/jersey-multipart-missing-start-boundary/35877972#35877972) to a similar issue which may also be the cause here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A colleague transform the content-type of every request with a lowercase in the netty implementation.
The none WebKit browser use a random numeric boundary but WebKit browser use an alpha numeric boundary with upper and lower case character.

Comment: what's the solution then?