# How to fix different multipart boundary implementations?

Tags: java, postman, multipartform-data, fetch-api, jersey-2.0

I created a file upload functionality in Jersey.

```
@POST
@Path("/import")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public static Response importFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData,
```

When I send a file as multipart formdata from the browser (Firefox and Chrome) using Fetch API or a jQuery POST, Jersey responds with a `org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary`.

This is apparently not due to the fact that e.g. Chrome uses a case-sensitive boundary, [as others have had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877972/3271380), since the issue happens in Firefox as well, which uses a numeric boundary.

It seems that in my case, the browser sends the boundary with two additional dashes before each boundary in the body and after the last one (which seems to be correct according to the multipart specification https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), but Jersey (2.25.1) / Mimepull (1.9.14) does not accept that.

```
Content-Type multipart/form-data; boundary=
---------------------------23978830417520517351040096390


-----------------------------23978830417520517351040096390
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testdata.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

<snip>
-----------------------------23978830417520517351040096390--
```

On the contrary, when I send my request using Postman, it encodes the boundary in the body without those two additional dashes and Jersey accepts the request.

```
POST /myapi/import HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 708
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testdata.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
    
<snip>

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

What is the correct behaviour in this case and how is it possible to implement the file upload in a way that different clients can use it?
Is there an alternative to using multipart implementation for file uploads?