# What if the form-data boundary is contained in the attached file?

Tags: forms, http, multipartform-data

Let's take the following example of `multipart/form-data` [taken from w3.com](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

It's pretty straight forward, but let's say you are writing code that implements this and creates such a request from scratch. Let's assume `file1.txt` is created by a user, and we have no control over its contents.

**What if the text file `file1.txt` contains the string `--AaB03x`?** You likely generated the boundary `AaB03x` randomly, but let's assume a ["million monkeys entering a million web forms"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) scenario.

Is there a **standard** way of dealing with this improbably but still possible situation?

Should the `text/plain` (or even, potentially something like `image/jpeg` or `application/octet-stream`) be "encoded" or some of the information within "escaped" in some sort of way?

Or should the developer always search the contents of the file for the boundary, and then repeatedly keep picking a new randomly generated boundary until the chosen string cannot be found within the file?

Comment: @DavidPostill I feel it's more on topic here than at StackOverflow as it's a question about the HTTP specification. I'm less interested in actually _developing_ a generator/parser, and more interested _learning how_ (or even if) this "edge case" has been solved.

Comment: "let's say you are writing code that implements this" ... "should the developer" ... "has been solved by others" -> [so] is where developers hang out...

Comment: This is not covered by the HTTP spec but by the *Mime specifications*. The boundary is a multipart artifact.

Answer (score 20):

HTTP delegates to the MIME RFCs for defining the `multipart/` types here. The rules are laid out in [RFC 2046 section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1).

The RFC simply states the boundary must not appear:

> The boundary
> delimiter MUST NOT appear inside any of the encapsulated parts, on a
> line by itself or as the prefix of any line.  This implies that it is
> crucial that the composing agent be able to choose and specify a
> unique boundary parameter value that does not contain the boundary
> parameter value of an enclosing multipart as a prefix.

and

> NOTE:  Because boundary delimiters must not appear in the body parts
> being encapsulated, a user agent must exercise care to choose a
> unique boundary parameter value.  The boundary parameter value in the
> example above could have been the result of an algorithm designed to
> produce boundary delimiters with a very low probability of already
> existing in the data to be encapsulated without having to prescan the
> data.  Alternate algorithms might result in more "readable" boundary
> delimiters for a recipient with an old user agent, but would require
> more attention to the possibility that the boundary delimiter might
> appear at the beginning of some line in the encapsulated part. The
> simplest boundary delimiter line possible is something like "---",
> with a closing boundary delimiter line of "-----".

Most MIME software simply generates a random boundary such that the probability of that boundary appearing in the parts is *statistically unlikely*; e.g. a collision could happen but the probability of that ever happening is so low as to be infeasible. Computer [UUID values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) rely on the same principles; if you generate a few trillion UUIDs in a year, the probability of generating two identical UUID values is about the same as someone being hit by a meteorite, both have a 1 in 17 billion chance.

Note that you usually encode binary data to some form of ASCII-safe encoding like base64, an encoding that doesn't include dashes, removing the likelihood that binary data ever contains the boundary.

As such, the standard way to deal with the possibility is to simply make the possibility so unlikely as to be next to nothing. If you have a greater chance of a computer storing the email being hit by a meteorite, why worry about the MIME boundary?

Comment: HTTP doesn't matter here; what's relevant is the definition of multipart/form-data in the IANA media types registry; and that refers RFC 2388.

Comment: @JulianReschke: RFC 2388 is the specific `multipart/` sub-type; it still doesn't determine how a boundary is picked. That is delegated to the general MIME RFCs. I did notice that I had cited an obsoleted RFC here; I updated to use the most recent RFC instead.