# PHP message: PHP Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I have a server application that is working as a rest server and it is receiving data from only one client application. I see this error in my nginx logs:

```
2015/10/27 04:34:33 [error] 12383#0: *69 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: yy.yy.yy.yy, server: xyz, request: "POST /availability/check_availability HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

What does that mean and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: I found out that the client application was not specifying the content-type when sending data.