# Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None

Tags: angularjs, node.js, form-data

I am very frustrated and could not find the soloution:

I am creating a project using angularjs and nodejs.I get image data from angular side in node js and send this data to further api.I got error

```
{
  "error": {
    "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"
  }
}
```

here is my code in nodejs side:

```
var request = require('request');
    console.log(req.files);
var data = {

        website:'www.gamail.xom',
        contact_number:'dsdsd',
        services_offered:'dsadasd',
        contact_name:'dasdas',
        provider_category:'exchange',
        email:'kk@gmail.com',
        image:req.files

    }
var api_url = global.common.base_url + 'vcard/1.0.0/visit_card/' + req.param('uuid') +'/';
    request({
        url: api_url,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+req.cookies.apitoken
        },
        json: data

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode == 200 && !error){
            res.end(JSON.stringify(body));
        }else{          
            res.send(response.statusCode, { error: body });
        }
    });
}
```

In req.files  i get

```
{ image:
   [ { fieldName: 'image[0]',
       originalFilename: 'icon_dd_chart_grey.png',
       path: 'C:\\Users\\karakuma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\op74_gLSzPs-_49aT1GF0si
7.png',
       headers: [Object],
       size: 1474,
       name: 'icon_dd_chart_grey.png',
       type: 'image/png' } ] }
```

Comment: How did you manage to solve the problem? Or it remains unsolved?

Comment: Try removing Content-Type Header?

Answer (score 7):

Try defining the content type as follows.

```
content_type='multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
```

I was facing the same issue and it worked for me in python.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here @Aamir

Comment: It could be a true solution but with no word of explanation seems useless

Comment: @Axel could you possibly explain the 'boundary=-----' part of your answer?

Comment: @DGG to be honest, I don't have a clue about it. I just made a very simple edit on the answer. But what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data or https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multipart%2Fform-data%3B+boundary%3D----&t=ffab&atb=v267-1&ia=web

Comment: @Axel thanks a ton for the helpful links. The SO link/answer by Oscar Mederos explained it really well. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help you out @DGG!

Comment: For somebody using `fetch`: this error happens too if you are trying to put this header manually and  providing the `FormData`  object as the body as well. You only need to give the `FormData` object and fetch will set this header for you automatically. [reference/info](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/505#issuecomment-293064470)

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for hours, until I read @StandardIO 's comment above. Thank you! Removing the Content-Type header did solve my problem!

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue while trying to upload file. For me the issue was the FormData, which was coming as `Object` instead of `FormData instance`

So i converted my object to FormData using below code:

```js
const getFormData = object => Object.keys(object).reduce((formData, key) => {
            formData.append(key, object[key]);
            return formData;
        }, new FormData());
```

And the just executed my post request, in my case using Vue resource:

```js
return Vue.http.post(url,
        getFormData(formData),
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to mention the content type in header, fetch() will detect it's content type by itself.

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append("email", email);
formData.append("password", password);
formData.append("image", image);

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/authentication/register/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}, //django specific
                body: formData,
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem in angular 11 connected to Django rest API, I was able to curl with something like this in order to upload a JSON with a form:

```
curl -X POST -S \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -u "user:password" \
  -F "name=name" \
  -F "label=mylabel" \
  -F "otherfields=something" \
  -F "photo=@./example.png;type=image/png" \
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/item/
```

But I was getting that exception using my header as httpOptions:

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
```

So I just commented out the `content-type` and it seems angular is so clever that he creates the header for you and will set the multipart together with the boundaries.

For more information on this:
[What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 0):

A boundary is just the 'key' to separate the multiple "parts" of a multipart payload. Normally something like '&' is enough to separate the variables but you need something more unique to separate the payloads within the payload  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data#comment34211123_20321259)

You can use any value that not occurs in the data sent.

> NOTE: Because boundary delimiters must not appear in the body parts being encapsulated, a user agent must exercise care to choose a unique boundary parameter value.

> The simplest boundary delimiter line possible is something like "---", with a closing boundary delimiter line of "-----".

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',`. And it works.