# PATCH and PUT don't work as expected when pytest is interacting with REST framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, put, pytest-django

I am building an API using the django REST framework.

To test this API I am using pytest and the test client like so:

```
def test_doesnt_find(self, client):
    resp = client.post(self.url, data={'name': '123'})
    assert resp.status_code == 404
```

or

```
def test_doesnt_find(self, client):
    resp = client.get(self.url, data={'name': '123'})
    assert resp.status_code == 404
```

both work when using the general GET, POST and DELETE Classes of the REST framework (like `DestroyAPIView`, `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` or just `APIView` using get and post functions)

Where I get problems is when using PATCH and PUT views. Such as `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`. Here I suddenly have to use:

```
resp = client.patch(self.url, data="name=123", content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

or

```
resp = client.patch(self.url, data=json.dumps({'name': '123'}), content_type='application/json')
```

If I simply try to use the test client like I am used to, I get errors:

```
rest_framework.exceptions.UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.
```

And when I specify 'application/json' in the client.patch() call:

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`
```

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? It is especially hard to catch as curl simply works as well using `-X PATCH -d"name=123"`.

Comment: What's the test client you are referring to ? Django's ? DRF's ? another one ?

Comment: it is the django test client [http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#client-django-test-client]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

This is usually sign that you send a string inside a string in json.
For example:

```
resp = client.patch(self.url, data=json.dumps("name=123"), content_type='application/json')
```

will cause this kind of issues.

> rest_framework.exceptions.UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.

This means that the request has been sent as "application/octet-stream" which is Django's test default.

To ease the pain with dealing with all that, Django REST framework provides a client on its own: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient

Note that the syntax is slightly different from Django's one and that you won't have to deal with json encoding.

Comment: Tip: rather than instantiating an `APIClient` you can just inherit from `APITestCase` for your test classes

Comment: ```resp = client.patch(self.url, json={"name": 123})```

Answer (score 3):

Pytest uses the django test client and [client.post](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) default content_type is *multipart/form-data*, while [put](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.put), [patch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.patch) and [delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.delete) use *application/octet-stream*.

That's why this is tricky sometimes. Even with post requests, if you plan to support JSON payload, you must tell the content type in the test request. Anyway, with recent Django versions, you can just pass the data object to the client request and it will be serialized for you, as declared in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post):

> If you provide content_type as application/json, the data is
> serialized using json.dumps() if it’s a dict, list, or tuple.
> Serialization is performed with DjangoJSONEncoder by default, and can
> be overridden by providing a json_encoder argument to Client. This
> serialization also happens for put(), patch(), and delete() requests.

For example:

```
resp = client.patch(self.url, {'name': '123'}, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the request with JSON data you are receiving this error due to [JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/) it needs **double quotes** over a string.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. But for the Googlers, you should use `format='json'` in the **django test client**.

Manual `json.dump`ing and setting `content_type` doesn't always work as expected.

```py
resp = client.patch(self.url, data={'name': '123'}, format='json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for put / patch for django TestCase class:

```
from django.test.client import encode_multipart

body = {
  'file': SimpleUploadedFile('file.xlsx', file_data, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'),
  'other_field': ...,
}

self.client.put(f'some_api/{id}/', encode_multipart(body), format='multipart', content_type='multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg')
```

By default content_type is `application/octet-stream`. [As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194096/19629893) boundary can be any value. Also check the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) for proper form-data formating. [Here is](https://github.com/django/django/blob/820c5f1bacd41713bd30d8b5fefb66752ff15c4c/django/http/multipartparser.py#L187)  the actual method that is causing the error if no boundary is specified.