# bad content-type header, no multipart boundary nodejs

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, superagent

I have an API that returns content with `content-type: "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"`. However, in my nodejs app, when I make the following call through `superagent`:

```
request
    .get(ApiUrl + id)
    .set('Authorization', basicHttpAuth)
    .set('client_id', clientId)
    .set('client_secret', clientSecret)
    .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback(null, err)
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, res);
        }
    })
```

I get this error:

> Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary

Any idea what's wrong?

Stack Trace:

```
Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary
    at IncomingForm._parseContentType (/Users/mike/Svr/Server/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:271:19)
    at IncomingForm.writeHeaders (/Users/mike/Svr/Server/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:142:8)
    at IncomingForm.parse (/Users/mike/Svr/Server/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:110:8)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/mike/Svr/Server/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:869:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:564:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:453:20) response: undefined }
```

Here is the server response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →44691
Content-Type →multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 05 Jul 2017 03:44:23 GMT
```

And the body is big blob of text / string.

Comment: I doubt you'd be allowed to use `--` as suffix for boundaries.

Comment: Ok but removing that didn't help

Comment: Setting `multipart/form-data` for a `GET` request doesn't really make sense anyway. Are you sure it's not supposed to be a `POST` request? Also, it doesn't look like you're actually uploading data, so perhaps the `Content-Type` header isn't even necessary at all.

Comment: Ok but removing even that doesn't work. The error remains the same. And yes I am not uploading any data, but what I am receiving has Content type "multipart/form-data"

Comment: The question is where the error is originating from. I initially thought that it was the server that was emitting that error, but now I understand it's the client? I don't expect `superagent` to parse `multipart/form-data` responses, so where's it coming from? Can you post the stack trace that belongs to the error?

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: Thanks. It looks like `superagent` _does_ parse `multipart/form-data` responses, but that the server response is invalid. Without knowing what the actual server response is, that's going to be difficult to debug. Perhaps you can use `request` instead of `superagent`, or use a tool like cURL to determine what the actual server response is.

Comment: just remove `content-type`

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt):

> ...while the "boundary" parameter is required for any subtype of the "multipart" media type.

In your case, the server doesn't set that parameter, so the response is invalid and `superagent` (which tries to parse the response) throws an error.

You may be able to use an alternative HTTP client, provided that it doesn't try to parse `multipart/form-data` responses.

You could use the built-in [`http(s).get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), or perhaps the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) package.

**EDIT**: if you're stuck with `superagent`, then you may be able to monkeypatch it so it will detect the broken response and treat it as `text/plain`.

Add the following somewhere "high up" in your code (before using `superagent`):

```
const Utils     = require('superagent/lib/utils');
const UtilsType = Utils.type;
Utils.type = function(type) {
  if (type === 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8') {
    type = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
  }
  return UtilsType.call(this, type);
};
```

Comment: No way to disable unnecessary superagent's parsing?

Comment: No, it's not a configurable option as far as I can see.

Comment: Can I make the server set the parameter somehow? We have to use superagent for all http calls, so we can't use any other http service.

Comment: You can only make the server set it if you can change its source code. I've edited my answer to provide a possibly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Normal while passing the multipart-formdata with files you need to set the boundry just incase if the file is of more size then the request made.

```
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42985029/10341083)