# Uploading file to openstack object storage from JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, openstack, form-data, angularjs-http, openstack-swift

I have a openstack object storage container to which I'm trying to upload files directly from browser.

As per the  documentation [here](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/), I can upload the file using a `PUT` request and I'm doing this using Angularjs provided `$http.put` method as shown below.

```
$http.put(temporaryUploadUrl,
    formData,
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    }
).then(function (res) {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

The file uploads successfully and it has no problems in authentication and gives me a `201 Created` response. However the file is now containing junk lines on the top and bottom of it because its a multipart request sent using `FormData()`.

**Sample file content before upload:**

```
Some sample text 
here is more text 
here is some other text
```

**File content after downloadiong back from openstack container :**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTEeQZVW5hNSWtIqS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="c.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Some sample text 
here is more text 
here is some other text
------WebKitFormBoundaryTEeQZVW5hNSWtIqS--
```

I tried the `FileReader` to read the selected file as a binary string and wrote the content to the request body instead of `FormData` and the request which works fine for text files but not the binary files like `XLSX` or `PDF` The data is entirely corrupted this way.

Comment: @georgeawg Please revisit the question again. I have edited the mistakes

Comment: Only if there were comments telling me why all these downvotes... :|

Comment: The "junk lines" are the [boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)  when sending `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. You tried everything **except** sending the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the selected file as a binary string and wrote the content to the request body instead of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and the request which works fine for text files but not the binary files like XLSX or PDF The data is entirely corrupted this way.

The default operation for the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is to use `Content-Type: application/json` and to transform objects to [JSON strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). For files from a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), the defaults need to be overridden:

```
var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} };

$http.put(url, fileList[0], config)
  .then(function(response) {
     console.log("Success");
}).catch(function(response) {
     console.log("Error: ", response.status);
     throw response;
});
```

By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) will automatically set the content type header appropriately.

Be aware that the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of `'Content-Type': multipart/form-data` adds 33% extra overhead. It is more efficient to send [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects directly.

Sending binary data as binary strings, will corrupt the data because the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) converts strings from [DOMSTRING (UTF-16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Avoid [binary strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) as they are non-standard and obsolete.

Comment: This didnt work when I tried uploading to Openstack temp url. The file entry is created however, the file downloads as 0 bytes.(Empty file)

Comment: Fixed it by removing `transformRequest: angular.identity` in your code. Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Blob detection was added to AngularJS v1.3.0 with [commit 7c858ce](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b8cc71d476f76ff51e719fb76fb2348027c858ce). FormData detection was added to v1.3.7 with [commit d80ce4a](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/40258838031604feecb862afdc6f1f503d80ce4a).

Comment: I'm using 1.3.17

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:***

> The following answer is now considered a less performing workaround As
>   it will encode the entire file to base64 multipart form data. I would
>   suggest go ahead with @georgeawg's Answer if you are not Looking for a
>   `formData` + `POST` solution

Openstack also provides a different approach using FormData for uploading one or more files in a single go as mentioned in this [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/api/form_post_middleware.html#form-post-example). Funny this was never visible in google search.

Here is a brief of it.

First you need to generate a signature similar to tempUrl signature using the following python procedure.

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1
from time import time
path = '/v1/my_account/container/object_prefix'
redirect = 'https://myserver.com/some-page'
max_file_size = 104857600
max_file_count = 1
expires = 1503124957
key = 'mySecretKey'
hmac_body = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (path, redirect,
max_file_size, max_file_count, expires)
signature = hmac.new(key, hmac_body, sha1).hexdigest()
```

Then in your javascript call post to the container like this.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("max_file_size", '104857600');
formData.append("max_file_count", '1');
formData.append("expires", '1503124957');
formData.append("signature", signature);
formData.append("redirect", redirect);
formData.append("file",fileObject);
$http.post(
    "https://www.example.com/v1/my_account/container/object_prefix",
    formData,
    {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }
).then(function (res) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

***Points to note.***

- The `formData` in `POST` request should contain only these
  parameters.
- The file entry in the formData should be the last one.(Not sure why
  it doesnt work the other way around).
- The formData content like path with prefix, epoch time, max file
  size, max file count and the redirection urls should be the same as
  the one which were used to generate the signature. Otherwise you will
  get a `401 Unauthorized`.