# Dynamically update content-type header when using Javascript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, excel, multipartform-data, content-type, fetch-api

I'm trying to send an http POST request using the JavaScript Fetch API. What I've got so far looks like this (in TypeScript notation):

```
const fetchHeaders = new Headers();
fetchHeaders.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=???");

const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "Post",
    body: this.file,
    headers: fetchHeaders
}

await fetch("uri", fetchOptions);
```

Assuming that `this.file` is either a `.xls` or `.xlsx` Excel file uploaded using a `<input type="file">`, how do I populate the `boundary=` part of the `Content-Type` header dynamically when the fetch is called?

When doing this same operation in POSTMAN, the boundary is automatically set and I can't figure out how.

Comment: Question re-posted because of an erroneous duplicate mark, since duplicated questions tend to get ignored.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data this is why they are saying its a duplicate

Comment: That's not the question they said was a duplicate. That one is also not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the core issue - passing the file itself as the body. This was how I solved it:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.file, this.file.name);

const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "Post",
    body: formData
}
```