# How do I upload a file using multipart/form-data header with native Node.js https.request?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file from my computer using native https.request from node.js. My code look like this:

```
let query = require('https').request({
  hostname: 'somehost.com',
  path: '/path/to/upload',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
  method: 'POST'
}, (res) => {
  let data = '';
  res.on("data", (chunk) => {
    data += chunk.toString('utf8');
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log("data");
  })
});
query.on("error", (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
query.write(Buffer[
  {key1: 1, file: require("fs").createReadStream("/path/to/file.txt")}
]);      // I don't know how to put here
query.end();
```

I don't get any response from host, the file failed to upload. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading multipart/form-data, the `Content-Type` header must include a [boundary](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4), in order to indicate where each "part" lives within the posted data. In order to set the boundary for [The Multipart Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), you can use the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package from NPM. You *could* [set the header/boundary manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194096/2630078), but the form-data package will handle this for you and free you from having to worry about the details, etc.

In order to use form-data in your example, you will need to do the following:

1. Create a new `FormData` object and `append` the relevant parts:

   ```
   let formData = new require('form-data')();
   formData.append('key1', 1);
   formData.append('file', require("fs").createReadStream("/path/to/file.txt"));
   ```
2. Use the `getHeaders` function to build the correct HTTP headers:

   ```
   require('https').request({
       headers: formData.getHeaders(),
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Use `pipe` in order to allow form-data to process your data and send it to the server:

   ```
   formData.pipe(query);
   ```

   With this change, you no longer need your calls to `query.write` or `query.end` - the call to `pipe` takes care of that.

For completeness, here's the final code with the changes I described:

```
let formData = new require('form-data')();
formData.append('key1', 1);
formData.append('file', require("fs").createReadStream("/path/to/file.txt"));

let query = require('https').request({
    hostname: 'somehost.com',
    path: '/path/to/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: formData.getHeaders()
}, (res) => {
    let data = '';
    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk.toString('utf8');
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
    })
});

query.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

formData.pipe(query);
```