# org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web app with such config. Please look at multipartResolver bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }


    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {

        final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);

        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

also I have controller, which should accept file from client

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/file/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("!!!");
        MultipartHttpServletRequest mRequest =
                (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request; // Exception is here
        //some code
    }
```

I send file in this jsp snippet

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
          <button ng-click="ctrl.add()">Add</button>
```

by this angular code

```
function functionAdd() {
        var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append("file", f);
        return $http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI1, fd);
    }
```

I've got this stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:410)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Maybe somebody can see a mistake.

Comment: what is this REST_SERVICE_URI1

Comment: it works properly
  `  var REST_SERVICE_URI1 = 'http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/file//`
with enitial mapping on `/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample`

Comment: you are using http or https?

Comment: as you can see `$http`

Comment: no. in the uri you have put above. Before localhost do you have `http://` ot `https://`

Comment: i have "http" (stackoverflow has deleted prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to POST FormData Using the $http Service

When using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to POST files and data, it is important to set the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `undefined`.

```
var fd = new FormData()
for (var i in $scope.files) {
    fd.append("fileToUpload", $scope.files[i]);
}
var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}};

var httpPromise = $http.post(url, fd, config);
```

By default the AngularJS framework uses content type `application/json`. By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the AngularJS framework omits the content type header allowing the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to set the content type. When sending a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), the XHR API sets the content type to `multipart/form-data` with the proper boundaries and [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR Send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

---

> Can you explain why it isn't proper to use `multipart/form-data`? instead of `undefined`.

`multipart/form-data` without the proper boundaries causes problems. The [XHR send() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) automatically sets the boundary and includes it with each part.

By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the AngularJS framework omits the content type header allowing the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to set the content type. When sending a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), the XHR API sets the content type to `multipart/form-data` with the proper boundaries and [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

For more information, see [What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)

Comment: I can consider this as a right answer. I've already done something similar and it works for me! thanks

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't proper to use `multipart/form-data`? instead of `undefined`.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` without the proper boundaries causes problems. The [XHR send() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) automatically sets the boundary and includes it with each part. For more information, see [What is the boundary in multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data).