# What is meaning of "<<", "--" in perl and implementation in php?

Tags: php, perl

I am converting some Perl code to PHP.
However, I do not know much about Perl, so I have to code it with a rough meaning.

And, I do not understand what the below Perl code means...

What is the meaning of `$req2->content(<<"POST_DATA")` and `--$boundary`?
I've searched the Perl [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/), but it's too hard to find.

PHP code:

```
...
$boundary= 'Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall'; 

$req2 = curl_init($search_url); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($req2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary='.$boundary, 
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)) 
); 
$result= curl_exec($req2); 
...
```

Perl code:

```
...
my $boundary= 'Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall';
$req2->content_type('multipart/form-data;boundary='.$boundary);
$req2->header("Cookie"=>"access_token_cookie=$access_token_cookie; csrf_access_token=$csrf_access_token");

$req2->content(<<"POST_DATA"); #what means this?

--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="num_result"
Content-Type: text/plain

$num_result
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"; filename="search.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

$image
--$boundary--
POST_DATA

my $res = $ua->request($req2);
...
```

Comment: This looks like [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). They're also explained in PERL on the [Here document wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing very different from PHP actually.

- `<<` Heredoc, also present in [PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) with slight differences:

  ```
  echo (<<<"POST_DATA"
  First line
  Second line
  POST_DATA
  );
  ```
- `--` Variable decrease, as in `<?php $a=2; echo --$a;`

**Note:**

Of course, inside a Heredoc `--` is just text.

---

**Suggestion:**

If you don't fully understand the Perl, try to run it (it's not evil code).

```
my $boundary = 'Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall';
print(<<"POST_DATA");

--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="num_result"
Content-Type: text/plain

$num_result
--$boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"; filename="search.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

$image
--$boundary--
POST_DATA
```

Will yield:

```
 
--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="num_result"
Content-Type: text/plain


--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"; filename="search.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


--Nobody-has-the-intention-to-erect-a-wall--
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> $req2->content(<<"POST_DATA"); #what means this?
> ```

The `<<"POST_DATA"` starts a [HERE document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), which is essentially a long string. The double quotes `""` tell Perl to do [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). That means that variables inside the string will be replaced with their content. The string ends when the parser encounters the delimiter, which in this case is the string `POST_DATA`.

The `--` you are referring to is not an operator. It's used inside of the string. The program sends a [`multipart/formdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Form-Data) form over HTTP. Look at [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) if you are interested in the technical details. Essentially, each part of the request body represents one document. It can be multi-line and contain lots of information. The boundary can be set in the HTTP headers, and is typically a long, random string that would not appear in any of the body parts. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321259/1331451) for a more detailed explanation.