# MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, apache, java-8, multipartform-data

**Given:**

`byteString` is

```
-----------------------------149742642616556
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test
-----------------------------149742642616556--
```

Then this code (not optimized):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(BOUNDARY_PATTERN); // "(?m)\\A-+\\d+$"
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(byteString);
String boundary = null;
while (matcher.find()) {
    boundary = matcher.group();
    contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
}
LOG.info("Content Type = " + contentType);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream multipartStream =
        new org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteString.getBytes()), boundary.getBytes());
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
multipartStream.readBodyData(bos); // throw error
byte[] byteBody = bos.toByteArray();
```

Throws this error:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:593)
```

What could be possibly wrong here? I would appreciate a help here.

Comment: Which bytes? The String in the question is the bytes

Comment: okay, that should be byteString.getBytes()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The issue seems to be due to a bad end of line and the way the boundary is retrieved.** According to a [RFC2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) quote taken from a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194096/4375327):

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter, "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as **a line consisting entirely of two hyphen** characters ("-", decimal value 45) **followed by the boundary parameter value** from the Content-Type header field, optional linear whitespace, and **a terminating CRLF**.

The problem lies precisely on two points: the **end of line type** and the **two hyphens** preceding the boundary parameter value.

## End of lines

Since your code doesn't show accurately the value of byteString, I tried both **LF** (`\n`) and **CRLF** (`\r\n`) end of lines to see what will happen.

It appears the issue is reproduced when a **bad** end of line - i.e. not CRLF - is ***right before*** the **last boundary**, as shown below:

```
String byteString=
    "-----------------------------149742642616556\r\n" +
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "test\r\n" + // <-- only \n here lead to a MalformedStreamException
    "-----------------------------149742642616556--\r\n";
```

It sounds like the MultipartStream fails to parse the begin of the boundary, since it doesn't catch a right end of line (CRLF) on the previous line. **So, I you used LF terminators, you should replace them by CRLF ones.**

## Boundary format

The RFC tells that a boundary *delimiter* is two hyphens + boundary parameter + CRLF. Your regexp doesn't catch only the boundary parameter value, it also includes the two hyphens. So I replaced this part:

```
// capturing group = boundary parameter value
String regexp="(?m)\\A--(-*\\d+)$";
// [...]
while (matcher.find()) {
    boundary = matcher.group(1);
    // [...]
}
```

## Working code

#### Runnable as a MCVE

The code you'll find below can be run in a console without Tomcat. Only [commons-fileupload-1.3.3-bin.tar.gz](http://apache.mediamirrors.org/commons/fileupload/binaries/commons-fileupload-1.3.3-bin.tar.gz) and [commons-io-2.6-bin.tar.gz](http://apache.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.apache.org/dist/commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.6-bin.tar.gz) are needed.

To view what's parsed by the `MultipartStream`, I temporarily replaced `bos` by `System.out` in the `readBodyData()` call (as told in the comments).

- To compile:

  ```
  javac Test.java -classpath ./commons-fileupload-1.3.3-bin/commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
  ```
- To run:

  ```
  java -classpath ./commons-fileupload-1.3.3-bin/commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar:./commons-io-2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar:. Test
  ```

### The code itself

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;

public class Test {
    public final static void main(String[] argv) {
    String byteString=
        "-----------------------------149742642616556\r\n" +
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "test\r\n" + // <-- only \n here lead to a MalformedStreamException
        "-----------------------------149742642616556--\r\n";

    String regexp="(?m)\\A--(-*\\d+)$"; // edited regexp to catch the right boundary

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(byteString);
    String boundary = null;
    String contentType=null;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        boundary = matcher.group(1);
        contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"";
    }

    System.out.println("boundary = \"" + boundary + "\"");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream multipartStream =
        new org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream
        (new ByteArrayInputStream(byteString.getBytes()), boundary.getBytes());
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        // Use the commented line instead the following one
        // To see what the multipartStream is reading (for debug)
        // multipartStream.readBodyData(System.out);
        multipartStream.readBodyData(bos);
    } catch (MultipartStream.MalformedStreamException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed Exception " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    byte[] byteBody = bos.toByteArray();

    // Displaying the body read
    for(byte c : byteBody) {
        System.out.format("%c", c);
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
boundary = "---------------------------149742642616556"
-----------------------------149742642616556
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test
```

Comment: I was badly stuck in this error and your solution worked. I replaced all LF to CRLF and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I found that `MultipartStream` is adding `\r\n--` as a prefix to the boundary, because I didn't have a newline at the beginning of the content I got the `MultipartStream.MalformedStreamException("Stream ended unexpectedly")` exception because the boundary couldn't be found.

Maybe it's because of an older `commons-fileupload` version or because I was reading the multipart content from an HTTP PUT request sent by `curl`

#### **tl;dr**

add a **newline** at the beginning of your content if nothing else helped so far.