# req.file is undefined using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Im setting up a server to run a blackjack game and I want to store profile pictures on amazon S3 using multer on the backend. However, whenever I try to send an image from my frontend to the backend, my req.file is undefined.

There are many posts with this probelm, but i have done most of what they said and its been to no avail.

my HTML input:

```
<fieldset>
                <legend>Create Account</legend>
                Username:<input type="text" id="createUser"><br>
                Password:<input type="password" id="createPW"><br>
                Screen Name: <input type="text" id="createScreen"><br>
                Profile Picture: <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
                <button id="createAccountButton">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
```

my frontend fetch (pure js):

```
fetch(ec2+"/image-upload", {method: "POST", body: file}).then(checkStatus).catch(function(e){console.log(e);});
```

my backend:
server.js

```
const singleUpload = upload.single('avatar');

app.post('/image-upload',function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
    singleUpload(req, res, function(err, some) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message}] });
      } 
      return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
    });
  })
```

upload:

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'cloud-bj-bucket',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: 'TESTING_METADATA'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.filename);
    }
  })
})
```

The error is within the backend part

EDIT:
here is how i am getting the image from the html

```
var file = document.getElementById("avatar").files[0];

fetch(ec2+"/image-upload", {method: "POST", body: file}).then(checkStatus).catch(function(e){console.log(e);});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to access `req.file` before `upload.single` is executed. Simply chain the middleware like:

```
const singleUpload = upload.single('avatar');

app.post('/image-upload', singleUpload, function(req, res) { // <-- mount it here
  console.log(req.file)
  // rest of the code
}
```

You could use `FormData` to set the correct headers and use it in your fetch call. However you would need a form element for that.

```
var file = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
var data = new FormData(file)
fetch(ec2+"/image-upload", {
  method: "POST",
  body: data
})
```

The easiest option would be to have form element and call the api directly without getting `fetch` involved:

```
<form action="/image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Account</legend>
    Username:<input type="text" id="createUser">
    Password:<input type="password" id="createPW">
    Screen Name: <input type="text" id="createScreen">
    Profile Picture: <input type="file"  id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
    <button type="submit" id="createAccountButton">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: i have chained it as you stated and it is still undefined

Comment: i do not but the console prints undefined just as before. Edit: i get this ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined```

Comment: so a form tag is required for sending images?

Comment: updated answer, sorry completely forgot (accidentally ignored) the `fetch` call part

Comment: you can use some arbitrary value, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data or refer updated answer

Comment: i believe your last edit with the HTML has worked, thank you