# How can I send multipart/form-data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to send request payload as following in JMeter:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeBikRH0JCrgmtTvt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

test
------WebKitFormBoundaryeBikRH0JCrgmtTvt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

testing
------WebKitFormBoundaryeBikRH0JCrgmtTvt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="configFile"; filename="test.json"
Content-Type: application/json


------WebKitFormBoundaryeBikRH0JCrgmtTvt--
```

So I tried to add the name and description part in Parameters tab with form-data as Content-type and added file in Files Upload tab in HTTP Request Sampler.

This is what I am getting in Request Body after execution:

```
POST data:
--t9u984dDyYVtn6R0e8-OiZQyWRv9gk1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

test
--t9u984dDyYVtn6R0e8-OiZQyWRv9gk1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"
Content-Type: form-data; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

testing
--t9u984dDyYVtn6R0e8-OiZQyWRv9gk1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="configFile"; filename="test.json"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--t9u984dDyYVtn6R0e8-OiZQyWRv9gk1--
```

I want to remove this part from the request for name and description part

```
Content-Type: form-data; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

This is resulting into failure with status code : 415
Need help on this please

Answer (score 0):

If standard [multipart HTTP Request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) generated by JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler when you tick `Use multipart/form-data` box doesn't work for you be aware that you can manually build the HTTP Request by using:

- [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to set [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header containing the [boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)
- [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) to load the contents of your .json file into the request body

Check [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/) for more comprehensive explanation and detailed example

Comment: oh seems I have not posted my query correctly, edited it now.

Comment: Then you did something wrong because given you send the same request as the browser does - it *should work as expected*