# How to post an image with form-data in Rest Client for VSCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, rest-client

The documentation for the VSCode Rest Client is lacking good explinations. Here is what they give as an example.

```
POST https://api.example.com/user/upload
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

title
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

< ./1.png
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Not sure what the `<` is for nor the `title`?

Answer (score 20):

For the boundary part, I recomend read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data).

`<` It´s a symbol to indicate input stream, the file you want to send needs to be in the same directory as the `.rest` file that the **restclient extension** uses.

**Quick response:** boundary is to define where each pair of fields passed in the form is begins and ends. In your example there are two form fields, `text="title"` and `image=1.png` the bytes image sequence.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

< ./1.png
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Other data such as `filename="1.png"` or `Content-Type: image/png` indicate additional information that the form loads by default when you select an image with a file type input.

**Another example for a field** `description`.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

All text of description.
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Answer (score 3):

this  "Rest Client" snippet works for me (solution from [here](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/332)).

*Note the `boundry=MfnBoundry` does not use a delimiter, while `--MfnBoundry` is used to open it, and `--MfnBoundry--` is used to close it.

```http
POST http://localhost:3000/api/upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MfnBoundry

--MfnBoundry
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

< ./test.txt
--MfnBoundry--
```