# How to change Content Length in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am stuck at very critical junction of my scripting in Jmeter, I have a requirement to upload a file on Azure storage and a Microservice which analyze the blob data to process further but it looks for certain size, example 8081920 bytes. I am successfully able to upload the the file of same size on Azure storage but the service returns size Mismatch.

If I upload the same file using Postman, service is able to process the image successfully. Below is the Postman request Header

x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Content-Type: image/raw
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: b9384ac9-7fbe-4ab8-834b-aef0d8114588
Host: xxxxxxx.blob.xxxxxx.windows.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
**Content-Length: 8081920**

**Jmeter Request Header**:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: image/raw
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
**Content-Length: 8082155**
Host: xxxxxxx.blob.xxxxxx.windows.net
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10

Any idea how to resolve this from where jmeter sending additional 235 Bytes but Postman doesn't.

Thanks,
Akshat

Answer (score 0):

[Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header is being automatically calculated by both tools as:

```
sum of request headers (bytes) + request body (bytes)
```

Given you haven't provided the body we cannot state where the inconsistency lives, from what I can see is that Postman sends `Postman-Token` and JMeter doesn't so JMeter's Content-Length should be less

In case of multipart file upload the discrepancy can be caused by different [boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) but it shouldn't have any impact on the image processing.

In any case given you're able to successfully upload the file using Postman and cannot do this using JMeter - you can just record the request from Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) - this way you will get confidence that requests are exactly the same. Just **make sure to copy the file you're uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request.

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, I tried recording the using HTTP Test Scripts, but when it comes to upload functionality  of AUT application Jmeter is getting hanged, I tried on version 5.1, 5.2 and 5.4, same thing it is  getting hanged. I know during recording logs are saved on recording.xml during recording, even that if I import, again tool hungs up.  Using Jmeter  I am successfully able to upload but a service after upload analyze the size which returns size Mismatch, but the same file name(with same size) works fine on postman. I am totally Clueless what do to, please help