# Sending files using python 'aiohttp' produce "There was an error parsing the body"

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, fastapi

I am trying to make two services communicate. The first API is exposed to the user.
The second is hidden and can process files. So the first can redirect requests.
I want to make of the post request asynchronus using aiohttp but i am facing this error : "There was an error parsing the body"

To recreate the error :
Lets say this is the server code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
async def transcript_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    pass
```

And this is the client code :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import aiohttp
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload_client")
async def async_call():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        headers = {'accept': '*/*',
                   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        file_dict = {"file": open("any_file","rb")}
        async with session.post("http://localhost:8000/upload", headers=headers, data=file_dict) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

**Description** :

- Run the server on port 8000 and the client on any port you like
- Open the browser and open docs on the client.
- Execute the post request and see the error

**Environment** :

- aiohttp = 3.7.4
- fastapi = 0.63.0
- uvicorn = 0.13.4
- python-multipart = 0.0.2

Python version: 3.8.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194096/13782669):

> If you are using one of `multipart/*` content types, you are actually required to specify the boundary parameter in the `Content-Type` header, otherwise the server (in the case of an HTTP request) will not be able to parse the payload.

You need to remove the explicit setting of the `Content-Type` header, the client `aiohttp` will add it implicitly for you, including the `boundary` parameter.