# Requests, FastAPI, Error in Minimial Code

Tags: file, python-requests, upload, multipart, fastapi

Please, this min code give me this error with request:
400 {"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
but it good working on swagger ui.

**main.py**

```
import shutil
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):  
    try:
        with open('save.txt', "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    except:
        return {'State':'Fail'}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
    return {'State':'Done'}
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1",
     port=8000, log_level="debug", reload="true")
```

**query.py**

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/upload'
headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
files = [
("file", ("file1.txt", open("F://test.txt", "rb"), "text/txt"))
]
response = requests.post(url, files=files,  headers=headers)    
print(response.status_code, response.text)   

# The response is :
# 400 {"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67776535/sending-files-using-python-aiohttp-produce-there-was-an-error-parsing-the-bod/67777054#67777054

Comment: It working @alex_noname

Comment: Yes, Alex, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It working without headers.

Sending files using python 'aiohttp' produce "There was an error parsing the body"

```
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```