# "File Upload" functionality is not working in Jmeter with HTTP2 sampler [with all versions of JMETER]

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using "File Upload" option in the HTTP2 sampler to execute the load test with > 4.0 Jmeter version.

I have tried to "File Upload" option in the HTTP2 sampler and observed that the path provided for the "file path" getting removed when we move across the other samplers, therefore it's not possible to use the file upload option in the HTTP2 sampler.

[Added data in File Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qmtq.png)

[Post moving to the another thread/sampler, "file path" got removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37lU3.png)

Is there any another way to use in "file path" in HTTP2 sampler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the functionality is implemented, you can create an [enhancement request in the plugin repository](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter). If you're a BlazeMeter Customer you can ask for implementation via [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) channel

1. For "normal" upload you can try using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
2. For [multipart/form-data upload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) you need to build your request manually providing all the parts of the payload separated by [boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) like it's described in [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) article

Comment: My request type is Post for HTTP2 and I am passing "Parameters" so can't use "Body Data" means in same request so  this function "__FileToString() function" can't be use.