# How to send multipart/form-data payload with TypeScript Obsidian library?

Tags: typescript, http, multipartform-data, obsidian

I'm developing a plugin for [Obsidian.md](https://obsidian.md/) that needs to make an HTTP request to an API that expects a file in a `multipart/form-data` payload. In order to ensure the plugin works on mobile, I have to use the `requestUrl` method [provided by Obsidian's TypeScript](https://marcus.se.net/obsidian-plugin-docs/reference/typescript/functions/requestUrl) lib in order to ensure the plugin will work on mobile, among some other compatibility reasons.

However, `requestUrl` expects the body to be a `string` or an `ArrayBuffer` - is there a way to convert `FormData` into a `string` or `ArrayBuffer`? Or am I taking the wrong approach to constructing the payload?

The interface:
https://marcus.se.net/obsidian-plugin-docs/reference/typescript/interfaces/RequestUrlParam

```js
/** @public */
export interface RequestUrlParam {
    /** @public */
    url: string;
    /** @public */
    method?: string;
    /** @public */
    contentType?: string;
    /** @public */
    body?: string | ArrayBuffer;
    /** @public */
    headers?: Record<string, string>;
    /**
     * Whether to throw an error when the status code is >= 400
     * Defaults to true
     * @public
     */
    throw?: boolean;
}
```

My code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
const data = new Blob([await this.app.vault.adapter.readBinary(fileToTranscribe.path)]);
formData.append("audio_file", data);

const options: RequestUrlParam = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://djmango-bruh:9000/asr?task=transcribe&language=en",
  contentType: "multipart/form-data",
  body: formData,
};

requestUrl(options).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}).
catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Current error:
`Type 'FormData' is not assignable to type 'string | ArrayBuffer | undefined'.`

Additional References:
[API Repo](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api)
[API Docs](https://marcus.se.net/obsidian-plugin-docs/)
[A working implementation of the method](https://github.com/denolehov/obsidian-git/blob/4aabbef1988381f4239eef5d55ccf1bb493586d5/src/isomorphicGit.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built a workaround, essentially I just inspected the valid requests from fetch/Postman and am now constructing the multipart/form-data payload in an identical format manually.

There may be an existing library or util function to do this in a cleaner way, if I don't find one I may write one myself if I need to send file payload requests in other parts of my plugin.

```js
// This next block is a workaround to current Obsidian API limitations: requestURL only supports string data or an unnamed blob, not key-value formdata
// Essentially what we're doing here is constructing a multipart/form-data payload manually as a string and then passing it to requestURL
// I believe this to be equivilent to the following curl command: curl --location --request POST 'http://djmango-bruh:9000/asr?task=transcribe&language=en' --form 'audio_file=@"test-vault/02 Files/Recording.webm"'

// Generate the form data payload boundry string, it can be arbitrary, I'm just using a random string here
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript
const N = 16 // The length of our random boundry string
const randomBoundryString = "djmangoBoundry" + Array(N + 1).join((Math.random().toString(36) + '00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, N)

// Construct the form data payload as a string
const pre_string = `------${randomBoundryString}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="audio_file"; filename="blob"\r\nContent-Type: "application/octet-stream"\r\n\r\n`;
const post_string = `\r\n------${randomBoundryString}--`

// Convert the form data payload to a blob by concatenating the pre_string, the file data, and the post_string, and then return the blob as an array buffer
const pre_string_encoded = new TextEncoder().encode(pre_string);
const data = new Blob([await this.app.vault.adapter.readBinary(fileToTranscribe.path)]);
const post_string_encoded = new TextEncoder().encode(post_string);
const concatenated = await new Blob([pre_string_encoded, await getBlobArrayBuffer(data), post_string_encoded]).arrayBuffer()

// Now that we have the form data payload as an array buffer, we can pass it to requestURL
// We also need to set the content type to multipart/form-data and pass in the boundry string
const options: RequestUrlParam = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://djmango-bruh:9000/asr?task=transcribe&language=en',
    contentType: `multipart/form-data; boundary=----${randomBoundryString}`,
    body: concatenated
};

requestUrl(options).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Full source [here](https://github.com/djmango/obsidian-transcription/blob/cf5029b7f9aca97396a3befa2f963f15c87fabca/main.ts)

Answer (score 1):

In case you'd rather avoid rolling your own, the `multi-part-lite` library seems to work well for this:

```
const form = new Multipart();
form.append("session_id", sessionId);
form.append("files", Buffer.from(await this.app.vault.adapter.read("Foo.md")), { filename: "Foo.md", contentType: "text/markdown" })
const body = (await form.buffer()).toString();


console.log(body);


await request({
    url: `http://${host}/learn`,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`,
    body,
})
```

Outputs:

```http
----MultipartBoundary283122172169
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session_id"

6257abbf-8b7f-421a-bca5-2935150b87c1
----MultipartBoundary283122172169
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Foo.md"
Content-Type: text/markdown

<Contents of Foo.md>
----MultipartBoundary283122172169--
```