# Can't set Content-Type header for axios with FormData

Tags: javascript, axios

In this example (client side):

```
axios({
    url: "/public-resolutions/decision-files/",
    method: "post",
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8",
    },
});
```

When I `console.log` the `config` inside axios request interceptor (e.g. here: `axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config)....`), *I can't see the Content-Type header*.
But if I replace the `data` with empty object like here:

```
axios({
    url: "/public-resolutions/decision-files/",
    method: "post",
    processData: false,
    data: {}, // ---> change this
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8",
    },
});
```

Then the header gets set.
Anyone aware of this behavior?

PS. The reason I was thinking about setting this header is because the server is receiving *file name* in latin1 encoding, which breaks the app in some cases. So I wanted to set UTF-8 encoding.

axios version: 0.27.2

---

This is form data:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("excel", excel);
for (let i = 0; i < pdfs.length; i++) {
 formData.append("pdfs", pdfs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: When using FormData to submit POST requests using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch_API with the multipart/form-data Content-Type (e.g. when uploading Files and Blobs to the server), do not explicitly set the Content-Type header on the request. Doing so will prevent the browser from being able to set the Content-Type header with the boundary expression it will use to delimit form fields in the request body.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object)

Comment: This is interesting but wouldn't you also be able to *also* manually set the boundary then inside Content-Type (as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) ? (in case you explicitly set it)

Comment: However you can use [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to set content-type for your formdata fields

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your FormData is not correct. You should have unique names for FormData or you can pass array to FormData (if needed).

So, instead of this code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("excel", excel);
for (let i = 0; i < pdfs.length; i++) {
 formData.append("pdfs", pdfs[i]);
}
```

Try this code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("excel", excel);
formData.append("pdfs", pdfs);
```

or if you want to send each `pdfs` with different names. You can do that too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem I described, even if I just send one excel the problem with headers remains.