# How to monitor multipart upload in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, upload

How can we monitor how much time JMeter took to send all part of my file while uploading to server. I'm able to get the info in bytes/sec but i want to get that for each part.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart request is a [single request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2046#section-5.1). The main purpose of it is sending multiple files and associated data as a single request to the server.

You cannot measure processing speed for a "part" on JMeter side. The only thing you can measure is how fast JMeter is sending the "part" but you will need to do some manual or automated processing for it.

First of all [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/). It can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

then you can look for the generated [multipart boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) in the log file and you will see the timestamps for writing each "part" into the stream:

[image]