# In pact js how to request a multipart form with boundary

Tags: node.js, typescript, pact

Consider a request to get a token such as:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
let data = new FormData();
data.append('client_id', 'SOMEID');
data.append('client_secret', 'SOMESECRER');
data.append('scope', 'ouauth.scope.read');
data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://url/oauth2/token',
  headers: { 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

And a test such as

```js
const  mockProvider = new Pact({
      consumer: 'some-consumer',
      provider: 'fake-provider',
      logLevel: 'debug',
    })

    mockProvider.addInteraction({
      uponReceiving: 'a request to get a new token',

      withRequest: {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/oauth2/token',

        body: like({
          client_id: config.clientId,
          client_secret: config.secret,
          grant_type: 'client_credentials',
          scope: config.oAuthScope,
        }),

        headers: {
          'Content-Type': like('multipart/form-data'),
        },
      },
      willRespondWith: {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: like(expectedToken),
      },
    })
  })
```

I keep receiving the error

> 2023-12-05T12:42:09.017174Z DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker
> pact_mock_server::hyper_server: Request did not match: Request did not
> match - HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /oauth2/token, query: None,
> headers: Some({"Content-Type": ["multipart/form-data"]}), body:
> Present(145 bytes) )    0) $ -> Failed to parse the expected body as a
> MIME multipart body: 'no boundary in content-type'

If I omit the body the test can pass, how would I go around bypassing the boundary? Calculating the boundary does not work as it seems to change on every request

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi was just thinking why are you using `like` for matching? Can you try to match it using regex pattern? Something like: 
`body: term({
      generate: 'client_id=SOMEID&client_secret=SOMESECRER',
      matcher: '^client_id=.*&client_secret=.*$',
    }),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated with [`pact-foundation/pact-js` issue 1140](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/1140), Pact JS does not natively support matching multipart form data with dynamically generated boundaries.

The original [Axios request](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) correctly sends multipart form data, but each request dynamically generates a new boundary. That makes it difficult to match in the Pact interaction, as Pact expects a consistent format to validate against.

In HTTP, `multipart/form-data` is used for efficiently uploading binary data or files as part of a `POST` request. The ["boundary" delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3508338/6309) is a string that separates the different parts of the multipart data, to know where one part ends and the next begins.
When a `multipart/form-data` request is made, the `Content-Type` header includes this boundary string. For example: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=abc123`.

Boundaries can be *dynamically* generated by the client (like a web browser or an HTTP client library such as Axios). That way, the boundary string does not accidentally appear in the data being sent, which could break the format of the request. That means every time you make a `multipart/form-data` request, a new, unique boundary string is generated.

When you define the expected request in a Pact test, you need to specify what the headers should look like, including any boundary in the `Content-Type` header if the request is `multipart/form-data`. But..., since the boundary is dynamic and changes with each request, it becomes challenging to match it exactly in a Pact test.

Hence, the '`no boundary in content-type`' error.

You could use a fixed boundary string in tests. That allows you to explicitly set and expect the same boundary string in your Pact interaction.

Or, as shown below, you can try and extract the actual request body from the Axios configuration, which includes the dynamically generated boundary. By using this exact body in your Pact interaction, you avoid the issue of having to predict or match the dynamic boundary.

```bash
+------------------------+       +-------------------------+       +------------------+
| TypeScript Application |       | Axios Request           |       | Pact Mock Server  |
| - Creates FormData     |       | - Sends multipart form  |       | - Matches Request |
| - Appends form data    | ----> |   request with FormData |       |   with extracted  |
| - Sends request        |       | - Extracts request body | ----> |   request body    |
| via Axios              |       |   from config           |       | - Validates       |
+------------------------+       +-------------------------+       |   interaction     |
                                                                   +------------------+
```

Your file (let's name it `OAuthTokenPactTest.ts`) would be:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import { Pact, Matchers } from '@pact-foundation/pact';

const { like } = Matchers;

const mockProvider = new Pact({
  consumer: 'some-consumer',
  provider: 'fake-provider',
  logLevel: 'debug',
});

const fetchToken = async () => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('client_id', 'SOMEID');
  data.append('client_secret', 'SOMESECRER');
  data.append('scope', 'ouauth.scope.read');
  data.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://url/oauth2/token',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    data,
  };

  // Send the request
  const response = await axios.request(config);

  // Extract the request body
  const requestBody = response.config.data;

  mockProvider.addInteraction({
    uponReceiving: 'a request to get a new token',
    withRequest: {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/oauth2/token',
      body: requestBody,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': like('multipart/form-data'),
      },
    },
    willRespondWith: {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
      body: like(/* expectedToken */),
    },
  });
};

fetchToken();
```

The key change is extracting the actual request body using `response.config.data`, instead of trying to match the multipart form's dynamic boundary in the Pact interaction. That bypasses the need to deal with boundary issues.
The Pact interaction is set up with the actual request body. That way, it matches what Axios sends, including the multipart form data structure and boundary.

That file should be in a directory dedicated to testing, especially if you are following a typical Node.js/TypeScript project structure. For instance:

```
project-root/
│
├── src/                      # Source files for the application
│   ├── app.ts                # Main application file
│   └──                   # Other application-specific files
│
├── tests/                    # Test files
│   ├── pact/                 # Pact-specific tests
│   │   ├── OAuthTokenPactTest.ts   # The modified file for OAuth token Pact test
│   │   └──               # Other Pact test files
│   └──                   # Other test files (unit, integration, etc.)
│
├── node_modules/             # Node.js modules
│
├── package.json              # Project metadata and dependencies
├── tsconfig.json             # TypeScript configuration
└── ...
```

The `tests/pact/` is the subdirectory specifically for Pact-related tests. That is where `OAuthTokenPactTest.ts` is located. It is better to separate Pact tests due to their unique setup and dependencies.

Comment: Sorry I was on leave, will recheck it and readd the bounty that seems to have expired. Thank!

Comment: @FabioCosta No problem, and no bounty needed (I use the bounties to find interesting question)